# Run Javascript Class function using toString and eval()

Tags: javascript, class, oop, eval, tostring

The following code snippet for some reason does not work, I will be happy to help .

```js
var MyClass = {
  doSomething: function() {
    alert('Hello');
  }
}

const evalString = 'new (' + MyClass.toString() + ')().doSomething()';

eval(evalString);
```

Comment: `MyClass` is not a class. Maybe you meant `class MyClass { doSomething() { alert('Hello'); } }`.

Comment: You get confused in the programming language, this is how a class is defined in javascript .

Comment: I’m not confused, and that’s really not how you define a class in JavaScript. Really.

Comment: @Ryan You're right! Welcome to answer down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your usage of `eval()`. Maybe you might briefly want to again read on the usage of `eval()` below.

### Don't use eval needlessly!

`eval()` is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run `eval()` with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, a third-party code can see the scope in which `eval()` was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.

`eval()` is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.

There are safer (and faster!) alternatives to `eval()` for common use-cases.

#### Accessing member properties

You should not use `eval()` to convert property names into properties. Consider the following example where the property of the object to be accessed is not known until the code is executed. This can be done with eval:

```
var obj = { a: 20, b: 30 };
var propName = getPropName();  // returns "a" or "b"

eval( 'var result = obj.' + propName );
```

However, `eval()` is not necessary here. In fact, its use here is discouraged. Instead, use the property accessors, which are much faster and safer:

```
var obj = { a: 20, b: 30 };
var propName = getPropName();  // returns "a" or "b"
var result = obj[ propName ];  //  obj[ "a" ] is the same as obj.a
```

You can even use this method to access descendant properties. Using `eval()` this would look like:

```
var obj = {a: {b: {c: 0}}};
var propPath = getPropPath();  // returns e.g. "a.b.c"

eval( 'var result = obj.' + propPath );
```

As in your own case, you had:

```
const evalString = 'new (' + MyClass.toString() + ')().doSomething()';

eval(evalString);
```

which `eval(evalString);` was wrongly used.

You might need to read more on [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to help you figure out what exactly you plan to archive and a better way of archiving it.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, I'm not going to use the code attached to the question, that's just an example of my problem

Comment: great to know that you understand it, I think you can also apply the same concept to your problem.

Comment: I am trying to capture an dom element from the function browser.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval()

Comment: More information in the attached link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools.panels/ElementsPanel/onSelectionChanged

Comment: can you maybe just post the github link of what you're talking about, it might be easier helping you out directly on what you're tryna do.

Comment: I'm not able to publish this project because the project is ordered for a client of my employer

Comment: I will try to explain briefly what this is about, I'm currently writing a devtools extension to take in the dom element marked by inspect.
This can only be done with the example in this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools.panels/ElementsPanel/onSelectionChanged

Answer (score 1):

Following @Ryan's comment, the answer is:

```js
class MyClass {
  doSomething() {
    alert('Hello');
  }
}

const evalString = 'new (' + MyClass.toString() + ')().doSomething()';

eval(evalString);
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have tried that earlier even before answering your question, but you will only end up with: `class MyClass{
  doSomething() {
    alert('Hello');
  }
}

const evalString = 'new (' + MyClass.toString() + ')().doSomething()';

console.log(evalString);
new (function MyClass() {
    
})().doSomething() 
undefined` And doesn't in any way makes sense to me.

Comment: Press on "Run code snippet" button it's works perfectly!

Comment: Perfectly with this: `Error: {   "message": "TypeError: (intermediate value).doSomething is not a function",   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js line 21 > eval",   "lineno": 1,   "colno": 1 }`?